# convert a normal array associated array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Good afternoon I have an arrangement that comes this way

```
[{"a", "hello"}, {"a", "Goodbye"}, {"a": "NEW"}]
```

but want it to be this way

```
["hello "," Goodbye "," NEW "]
```

in javascript, I hope you can help me thanks.

Comment: Did you tried some thing?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you want to say {"a": "hello"}, but not {"a", "hello"}.
This code should work :

```
var origin =  [{"a": "hello"}, {"a": "Goodbye"}, {"a": "NEW"}];
var result = [];
for(item in origin){
    if(origin.hasOwnProperty(item)){
        var val = origin[item].a;
        result.push(val);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL7t0ej7/).